# Manipulating dynamically created JSON string in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I am working with Monday.com API which accepts GraphQL queries like this:

```
var query = @"{ ""query"": ""mutation {create_item(board_id: 12, column_values:\""{\\\""text\\\"":\\\""" + row.CampaignReference + @"\\\""}\"") { id} }"" }";
```

Basically column_values part that you see and that I want to generate dynamically is some kind of json-encoded string.

The MondayApi only accepts column_values in this format:

```
{\\\\\\\*text\\\\\\\*:\\\\\\\*value\\\\\\\*}
```

When I tried to create this Json for column values:

```
public static string CreateColumnValuesStrng(CampaignStatsusReportRow row)
        {
            string builder = string.Empty;
            dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
            foreach (var property in row.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                switch (property.Name)
                {
                    case "CampaignReference":
                        {
                            var columnname = @"\""" + property.Name+  @"\""";
                            var columnvalue = @"\""" + row.CampaignReference + @"\""";
                            ((IDictionary<string, object>)obj)[columnname] =columnvalue;                                  
                            break;
                            // more cases

                        }
                }              

            }
            var scriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return scriptSerializer.Serialize(obj);
        }
```

Unfortunately JsonConvert.SerializeObject adds one slash and quote for escaping at the end and beginning of each key value and I cannot achieve the same string format required.

I will be so grateful if someone can help me how to fix these ugly code with slashes  and generate this Json dynamically.
Thank you so much!

Comment: So the issue you have is that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` is not parsing as you expected? Would `JObject.Parse()` be a viable option here?

Comment: have you tried changing the string escape handling? See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_StringEscapeHandling.htm

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing input values for `property.Name` and `row.CampaignReference`, and desired JSON to be returned -- i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: thank you so much @dbc ! basically just replace row.campaign reference with a string and row.campaignreference with a string and  the goal is to get the same string as string query,  just in the column_values - you see {\\\""text\\\"":\\\""" + row.CampaignReference + @"\\\""}  this should be generated dynamically - the 'text' string can be 'text12'' and so on. Thank you as a junior developer I am a little bit struggling and I am thankful for any help.